# How to reduce APK size of PDF Reader in Android? - Java

Tags: java, android, pdf, storage

I have build a PDF Reader lite version but the release apk size is 22mb I want to make is smaller. I have used only 9 vectors icons and 1 webp image.

It has only two activity ManiActivity and PDF_ViewerActivity

MainActivity will get all pdf from user and show it in recyclerview using a PDF_Adapter and PDF_ViewHolder

PDF_ViewerActivity will show the pdf using :

```
'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

All dependencies used:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

can i make my apk smaller without removing any dependencies

Comment: Most of your size is coming from `android-pdf-viewer`. If you are going to be distributing your app as an App Bundle, the size for your users will be a lot lower, as `android-pdf-viewer` has binaries for different CPU architectures, and the Play Store will only send down to the device the binary that matches that device's architecture.

Comment: Android PdfViewer depends on PdfiumAndroid, which is set of native libraries (almost 16 MB) for many architectures. Apk must contain all this libraries to run on every device available on market. Fortunately, Google Play allows us to upload .abb,, use [app bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) for reduced apk size as it will load only one native library as per device architectures

Comment: i have build the .aab version but the app size decreased to 20MB. Do you mean that if i upload this aab file on Google Play it will load only one native library for different CPU architectures and it will reduce the final apk size. Am i correct? @Nitish

Comment: Yes , your .aab will be of the same size as of apk, but when you deploy it on play store, .abb will be dynamically generated into device specific app(handled by playstore) , this apk will be of reduced size.

Comment: `Google Play it will load only one native library for different CPU architectures` - not one library for different CPU architectures , but the library compatible with that CPU architecture. You apk size may wary from device to device, say one device will have size of 11 mb while other may be of 13mb's depending the library loaded into it

Comment: Thank You @Nitish